# Motion Tracking

Tags: edit-mode, video, tracking

why does the message "some data failed to reconstruct" come up when i solve camera motion? Im working on a gaming montage, so what i did was use the dolly camera from Call of Duty Black ops 2  to create a cinematicand recorded it using a Hauppage. Now i followed the tutorial from blender guru https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY and at the part of adjusting focal length and sensory width i did not know what to do because the dolly camera is not an actual real camera with camera specs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the focal length of camera, and is not specifically about blender.

Comment: how does that not have to do with blender...i'm trying to motion track on blender.

Comment: Blender related motion tracking questions are more than welcome, but requests for information about the lens parameters of a specific camera is not about blender. Such a question would likely be a better fit on a forum about the video game (in this case), or maybe [photography.se](http://photo.stackexchange.com/) in the case of a real camera.

Comment: its not a real camera its a digitally animated camera created by a game...where do i ask that?

Comment: You *could* try on [arqade.se](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not sure if you'll have any more luck there. For future reference, it's best to create an entirely new post when asking a different question

Comment: last thing...can i do the motion track with a 4.3 solve error

Comment: Well, pretty sure you'll get some odd results with that high of an error. That said, feel free to post a new question where more people will likely see it, I haven't done a lot of tracking..

Comment: @Daniel, please edit your question and add more information so someone can help you. As it stands right now there are a multitude of reasons why you can't track. Better still post a link to the video you are working with and your blend file.    4.3 solve error is still to high. Try to bring it down to less than 1, preferably less than 0.3.     Also to determine the focal length of  a camera lens try using BLAM on a single frame.

Comment: okey dokey..hold up.